# CKEditor4 destroy, not preserve original HTML content. How to disable filters?

Tags: html, ckeditor

I am using the standard demos, [like this](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/replacebyclass.html). So, the main options (little changes) can be flagged at `config.js`.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15525930/287948) when edit by source-code-HTML (button *Source*): elements (tags)  with *class* attribute, lost the attribute (`class` has been stripped out).

So, **how to disable the "default filter"?**

The "filtering by default" behaviour is a problem: is not backwards compatible, and, mainly, not a expected behaviour, because destroy the original content, that you must only change with editor.

Similar questions:

- [CKeditor allowedContent behaving oddly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16595485/)
- [CKEditor classes being stripped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15525930/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At `config.js` you can add something like,

```
  CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent=true;
```

see "Advanced Content Filter" ([ACF](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.1-Released)) and [how to enable/disable it](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent).

Comment: This is a correct answer from the point of view of developer integrating CKEditor with some system (although it is recommended to extend [ACF](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) settings rather than switch it off completely). However, developer working on a plugin should read [blog post about integrating plugins with Advanced Content Filter](http://ckeditor.com/blog/Integrating-Plugins-with-Advanced-Content-Filter).

Comment: Thanks (!), and thanks about this issue of new plugin, I'll read  it slow later.

Comment: Ran into a similar problem trying to load a new document using js: CKEditor was stripping all the headers. That was fixed with config.fullPage=1. The other problem was it was still changing the page headers. Google brought us here. Adding config.allowedContent=true helped, thanks.

But it was still changing the title and changing tags around. Turns out we were using the wrong method to load new HTML documents into the editor. Use editor1.setData(); instead.

Comment: Hello @hellork, I'm no longer involved with using CKEditor as in 2013, I also assume that the software has changed a lot after almost 4 years. Suggestion: post your comment as a answer (!), starting with the notice that is 2017 and is using version 4.6+

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem recently, 2017, version 5.5 developing a [file load / save plugin](http://thenerdshow.com/edit.html) and a [speech recognition plugin](http://thenerdshow.com/edit.html) for CKEditor (in progress). The above solutions helped, but also we had to use editor1.setData() to load the content into the editor.

Using select all and insertHTML() or insertText() methods was disrupting tags.